# POST binary file to PHP via C++ socket

Tags: php, c++, sockets, post

I'm trying to send a binary file via socket. I captured Curl headers to try reverse engineer it. My application and curl request seem the same to me but the PHP script fail to receive the file.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <winsock.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "wsock32.lib")

/***************** PROTOTYPE *******************/
int SockRecv(SOCKET sock);
int SockSend(SOCKET sock, std::string request);
std::streamoff FileSize(std::string filename);
int HTTP_POST(SOCKET sock, std::string host, std::string filename);
int SendFile(SOCKET sock, std::string filename);
/***************** PROTOTYPE *******************/

int main(){

        /* Standard networking stuff */
        u_short Port = 8080;
        const char* IP = "192.168.1.140";
        std::string host(IP);
        host += ":" + std::to_string(Port);

        WSAData wsa;
        WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(1, 1), &wsa);
        SOCKET sock;
        sockaddr_in RemoteSin;
        RemoteSin.sin_family = AF_INET;
        RemoteSin.sin_port = htons(Port);

        if ((RemoteSin.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr(IP)) == INADDR_NONE){
                std::cout << "Error setting IP: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
                return 1;
        }
        if ((sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR){
                std::cout << "Error creating socket" << std::endl;
                return 1;
        }

        if (connect(sock, (sockaddr *)&RemoteSin, sizeof(sockaddr_in)) == SOCKET_ERROR){
                std::cout << "Error connecting to remote host: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
                return 1;
        }

        /* Sending the binary file */
        HTTP_POST(sock, host, "test.exe");

        /* Closing and cleaning connection */
        closesocket(sock);
        WSACleanup();

        getchar();
}

std::streamoff FileSize(std::string filename){

        std::ifstream file(filename, std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);
        return file.tellg();
}

int HTTP_POST(SOCKET sock, std::string host, std::string filename){

        std::string header;
        std::streamoff lenght = FileSize(filename);

        /* Pre-building body to get the size  */
        std::string strSize = "------------------------448eacc7eda1d5ef45\r\n";
        strSize += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\"; ";
        strSize += "filename=\"" + filename + "\"\r\n";
        strSize += "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n";
        strSize += "\r\n------------------------448eacc7eda1d5ef45--\r\n";

        /* Calculating Content-Lenght */
        lenght = lenght + strSize.size();

        /* Building header */
        header = "POST /upload.php HTTP/1.1\r\n";
        header += "User-Agent: Bot\r\n";
        header += "Host: " + host + "\r\n";
        header += "Accept: */*\r\n";
        header += "Content-Length: " + std::to_string(lenght) + "\r\n";
        //      header += "Expect: 100-continue\r\n"; // Curl send this but I think this is not required and might only complicate things      
        header += "Content-Type: multipart/form-data-stream; ";
        header += "boundary=------------------------448eacc7eda1d5ef45\r\n\r\n";

        /* Appending first part of body to header */
        header += "------------------------448eacc7eda1d5ef45\r\n";
        header += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\"; ";
        header += "filename=\"" + filename + "\"\r\n";
        header += "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n";

        /* Sending header with first part of body */
        if (!SockSend(sock, header)) {

                /* Sending binary file */
                if (!SendFile(sock, filename)){

                        /* Closing body by sending end of boundary string */
                        std::string header_end = "\r\n------------------------448eacc7eda1d5ef45--\r\n";
                        if (!SockSend(sock, header_end)){

                                /* Printing server response to stdout */
                                if (!SockRecv(sock)){
                                        return 0;
                                }

                                return 1;
                        }
                }
        }
        return 1;
}

int SockSend(SOCKET sock, std::string request){

        if (send(sock, request.c_str(), strlen(request.c_str()), 0) == SOCKET_ERROR){
                return 1;
        }
        return 0;
}

int SockRecv(SOCKET sock){

        char reply[1024];
        ZeroMemory(reply, 1024);
        if (recv(sock, reply, 1024, 0) == SOCKET_ERROR){
                return 1;
        }
        std::cout << reply << std::endl;

        return 0;
}

int SendFile(SOCKET sock, std::string filename){

        char buf[1040];
        std::ifstream infile;
        infile.open(filename.c_str(), std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);

        if (infile.fail() == 1)
        {
                infile.close();
                return 1;
        }

        while (!infile.eof())
        {
                infile.read(buf, sizeof(buf));
                if (send(sock, buf, infile.gcount(), 0) == SOCKET_ERROR){
                        return 1;
                }
        }

        infile.close();
        return 0;
}
```

Here is the receiving PHP script:

```
<?php

// Where the file is going to be placed
$target_path = "upload/";

/* Add the original filename to our target path.  
Result is "uploads/filename.extension" */
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']).
    " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}

?>
```

Using this curl request:

```
curl --form "uploadedfile=@test.exe" http://192.168.1.140:8080/upload.php
```

This is what a successful upload looks like:

```
Request:
POST /upload.php HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
Host: 192.168.1.140:8080
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 69328
Expect: 100-continue
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------bfaa9a39adfbb3c1

--------------------------bfaa9a39adfbb3c1
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploadedfile"; filename="test.exe"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

/* Binary data */
--------------------------bfaa9a39adfbb3c1--

Response:
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.2.6 (Ubuntu)
Date: Tue, 08 Apr 2014 19:45:38 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.9-4ubuntu2.4
Content-Length: 35

The file test.exe has been uploaded
```

Then using my C++ application this is what a failed upload looks like:

```
Request:
POST /upload.php HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Bot
Host: 192.168.1.140:8080
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 69328
Content-Type: multipart/form-data-stream; boundary=------------------------448eacc7eda1d5ef45

------------------------448eacc7eda1d5ef45
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploadedfile"; filename="test.exe"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

/* Binary data */
------------------------448eacc7eda1d5ef45--

Response:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.2.6 (Ubuntu)
Date: Tue, 08 Apr 2014 19:45:49 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.9-4ubuntu2.4
Content-Length: 56

There was an error uploading the file, please try again!
```

I omitted the "Expect: 100-continue" because I think this is optional. Otherwise, both request looks exactly the same to me. Triple checked everything I could but now I am stuck there.

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong headers:

```
    header += "Content-Type: multipart/form-data-stream; ";
                                                ^^^^^^^---- wrong type
```

It should be just `multipart/form-data`.

As for your PHP code, you're failing to check for a successful/valid upload, and simply assuming everything worked perfectly:

```
if ($_FILES['uploadedfile']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    die("Upload failed with error code" . $_FILES['uploadedfile']['error']);
}
```

if you had even this minimal error handling, you'd have been told there was no upload to begin with, rather than finding out later when you try to move the file which doesn't exist.

Comment: Using multipart/form-data is one of the first thing I tried. I edited my code to multipart/form-data and added error checking to the PHP script. Now I get error 0 from the PHP script so I will continue to investigate since it seems like not file is uploaded.